# Unable to get desktop video stream in MacOS

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm using `desktopCapturer` api from electron which actually works fine on Windows for both locally served and final exe application. But on macOS it only shows the stream while developing the application or served locally. But shows a **blank white screen** on final dmg application. More specifically we are able to **control** or see the screen of window on the mac screen but unable to **control** or **see** the Mac screen on any other platform (only in production build but works fine in local development). I tried adding Info.plist file with `NSScreenCaptureUsageDescription` but it still is same.
Below is the package.json and code for sharing screen file. [image]

While launching the final build application a popup is shown for Accessibility Settings where i have already selected this application to access the screen of this device.

What could be the possible reason for a electron application not showing the stream

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import JoinCode from "./joincode";
import Peer from "simple-peer";
import FileShare from "../fileSharing/index";
import { Button } from "antd";
import Request from "../../request";

// const { RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription } = window;

function SharingPage(props) {
  const { connectionRef, yourRoomId, answerCallDATA } = useSelector(
    (state) => ({
      connectionRef: state.global.connectionRef,
      yourRoomId: state.global.yourRoomId,
      answerCallDATA: state.global.answerCallDATA,
    })
  );
  // const [downloadInProgress, setDownloadInProgress] = useState(false)
  const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState(null);
  const [resolution, setResolution] = useState({
    width: null,
    height: null,
  });
  const [Stream, setStream] = useState();
  const [receivingCall, setReceivingCall] = useState(false);
  const [caller, setCaller] = useState("");
  const [clearConnection, setClearConnection] = useState(false);
  const [callerSignal, setCallerSignal] = useState();
  const [callAccept, setCallAccept] = useState(false);
  const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [cancelSession, setCancelSession] = useState(false);
  const videoData = useRef();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    startShare();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setReceivingCall(false);
  }, [yourRoomId]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    let { success, data } = await Request.listCSessions({
      socketid: yourRoomId,
    });
    if (success && data) {
      await Request.updateCSessions({
        socketid: yourRoomId,
        current_plan_id: answerCallDATA?.current_plan_id,
      });
    }
  }, [callAccepted]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.ipcRenderer.on("stream", async (event, value) => {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
            chromeMediaSourceId: value?.sourceId,
            minWidth: value?.videoResolution?.width,
            maxWidth: value?.videoResolution?.width,
            minHeight: value?.videoResolution?.height,
            maxHeight: value?.videoResolution?.height,
          },
          // video: true,
        },
      });
      setStream(stream);
      setRoomId(value?.userId);
      dispatch({ type: "SET_USER_ROOMID", payload: value?.userId });
    });

    window.ipcRenderer.on("answerCall", async (event, data) => {
      setReceivingCall(true);
      setCaller(data.from);
      dispatch({ type: "SET_SOCKET_ID", payload: data.from });
      dispatch({ type: "SET_ANSWERCALL_DATA", payload: data });
      // setName(data.name)
      setCallerSignal(data.signal);
      setResolution({
        width: data.screenResolution.width,
        height: data.screenResolution.height,
      });
    });

    window.ipcRenderer.on("CallConnectDisconnnect", async (event, data) => {
      if (data == "Accept") {
        setCallAccept(true);
        setCancelSession(false);
      } else if (data == "Disconnect") {
        setCallAccept(false);
        setCancelSession(true);
      } else if (data == "Reject") {
        setReceivingCall(false);
        setCallAccept(false);
        setCancelSession(true);
        dispatch({ type: "INCOMING_ACCEPTED", payload: false });
        window.ipcRenderer.send("closedSession", {
          room: caller,
          Reject: true,
        });
      }
    });

    window.ipcRenderer.on("socketDisconneted", (event, value) => {
      setCancelSession(true);
    });

    window.ipcRenderer.on("clearConnection", (event, value) => {
      setClearConnection(true);
    });

    return () => {
      window.ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("stream");
      window.ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("answerCall");
      window.ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("CallConnectDisconnnect");
      window.ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("clearConnection");
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setReceivingCall(false);
    dispatch({ type: "SET_PEER_CONNECTION", payload: null });
    dispatch({ type: "INCOMING_ACCEPTED", payload: false });
    dispatch({ type: "SET_SOCKET_ID", payload: null });
    setStream();
  }, [clearConnection]);

  const startShare = () => {
    window.ipcRenderer.send("start-share", {});
    // setShare(true)
  };

  const accRej = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomId != null) {
      setInterval(() => {
        window.ipcRenderer.send("clipBoard", { roomId });
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, [roomId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (receivingCall == true) {
      window.ipcRenderer.send("Accept-Call", {});
    }
  }, [receivingCall]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (callAccept == true) {
      answerCall();
      setReceivingCall(false);
      setCallAccept(false);
    }
  }, [callAccept]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cancelSession == true) {
      window.ipcRenderer.send("closedSession", true);
      setReceivingCall(false);
      connectionRef?.destroy();
      dispatch({ type: "SET_PEER_CONNECTION", payload: null });
      dispatch({ type: "INCOMING_ACCEPTED", payload: false });
      setStream();
      dispatch({ type: "SET_FILE_RECEIVED", payload: false });
    }
  }, [cancelSession]);

  const answerCall = () => {
    const peer = new Peer({
      initiator: false,
      trickle: false,
      stream: Stream,
    });
    peer.on("signal", (data) => {
      window.ipcRenderer.send("answerInCall", {
        signal: data,
        from: yourRoomId,
        to: caller,
        resolution: resolution,
      });
    });
    peer.on("stream", (stream) => {
      // videoData.current.srcObject = Stream;
    });

    peer.on("connect", (msg) => {
      setCallAccepted(true);
      setCancelSession(false);
      dispatch({ type: "INCOMING_ACCEPTED", payload: true });
      dispatch({ type: "SET_PEER_CONNECTION", payload: peer });

      videoData.current.srcObject = Stream;
    });

    peer._pc.ondatachannel = (data) => {
      if (data.channel.label == "mouseChannel") {
        data.channel.onmessage = (event) => {
          window.ipcRenderer.send("mouseCoords", event.data);
        };
      }
      if (data.channel.label == "mouseClickChannel") {
        data.channel.onmessage = (event) => {
          window.ipcRenderer.send("mouse-click", event.data);
        };
      }
      if (data.channel.label == "keyChannel") {
        data.channel.onmessage = (event) => {
          window.ipcRenderer.send("key-up", event.data);
        };
      }
    };

    peer._pc.onconnectionstatechange = (data) => {
      if (peer._pc.connectionState == "connected") {
        setCallAccepted(true);
        setCancelSession(false);
        dispatch({ type: "INCOMING_ACCEPTED", payload: true });
        dispatch({ type: "SET_PEER_CONNECTION", payload: peer });

        videoData.current.srcObject = Stream;
      }
      if (peer._pc.connectionState == "disconnected") {
        setCallAccepted(false);
        setCancelSession(true);
        window.ipcRenderer.send("closedSession", true);
        setStream();
        dispatch({ type: "SET_FILE_RECEIVED", payload: false });
        dispatch({ type: "SET_FILER_DATA", payload: 0 });
      }
    };

    peer.on("error", (err) => {
      // setCancelSession(true)
      console.log(err, "erroorrr");
      setStream();
      dispatch({ type: "SET_FILE_RECEIVED", payload: false });
      dispatch({ type: "SET_FILER_DATA", payload: 0 });
    });

    peer.signal(callerSignal);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <video
        ref={videoData}
        autoPlay
        style={{
          opacity: 0.6,
          zIndex: -1,
          width: "90vw",
          height: "90vh",
          position: "absolute",
          padding: 0,
        }}
      ></video>
    </>
  );
}

export default SharingPage;
```

Comment: To maximise the chance of receiving an answer please edit your question by replacing the images of your code with actual code / text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2627338 for more information.

Comment: @midnight-coding Thanks for the information. But however i believe its somewhat related to build issues. Because everything works fine and perfectly when working locally. It only occurs in mac production i.e Windows cant control or see the screen in final dmg application.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. It was my MacOS bug. I have to go into **Accessibility** and **Screen** **Recording** Section in Settings and Privacy in System Preferences.
Although my application was already there but I had to remove it and manually add it again in both the section.